# Which Java libraries can be used to generate KML?

Tags: java, api, kml

I am looking for Java libraries to produce data in KML format.

Comment: did you manage to generate KML in java ? I tried JAK in play framework and was not successful.

Comment: We ended up using kmlframework.

Comment: try OSMBONUSPACK! https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/KML

Answer (score 13):

It appears there are at least three Java libraries for Keyhole Markup Language (KML):

- [JAK](https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml/)
- [gekmlib](http://code.google.com/p/gekmllib/)
- [kmlframework](http://code.google.com/p/kmlframework/)

As far as the best, that would depend on your needs.  JAK appears to be the best supported at the present time.

Comment: Just an FYI on gekmlib, as posted on the gekmlib google code wiki page 'This project hasn't been updated for several years. If you would like to take over the project feel free to message me.  It seems the version of KML used by Google Earth is 2.2 nowadays (March 2011). This library was written for 2.1 so you might not be able to access all elements.'

Comment: JAK is no longer maintained, see [this](https://github.com/micromata/javaapiforkml/issues/18) issue on GitHub.