# Beginners trouble on getting started with WorldWind and KML

Tags: java, geospatial, kml, jmonkeyengine, worldwind

I have an existing application that displays the ship track information using jmonkeyengine as shown in the image. I have the track data (long and lat etc). I am wondering how to show the ship track with the data I've using worldwind.

The green points are the geo cordinates and the blue image is the ship in the image.

One of the person on worldwind forum mentioned "Converting your data to KML would be the easiest way to display it in WW." I am not sure how to get started with that process either. I googled but couldn't find anything. I am new to all this so any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You could try using [JAK](http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home/) as recommended in this [Java-KML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952024/which-is-the-best-java-library-to-generate-kml) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the examples in the worldwind source, I realized they are using raw api's to create the KML document (KmlRoot). This doesn't work for me so I started using [JAK: Java Api for KML](http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/Home/) as it provides a fluent interface on top of KML standard. Thanks to @MarkJ.